# Build context folder in a remote registry?

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure a docker build in Jenkins using the docker build step plugin.

I am adding a build step in the project that needs to create an image using a dockerfile

[image]

My docker file in  the location `10.113.57.164:root/tapash_docker`

What should be format/value for `build context folder` for this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your slave is executing this job on 10.113.57.164, then your folder should be:

```
 /tapash_docker
```

That is where your Dockerfile is, and anything below `/tapash_docker` will be part of the build context.